# Condition in where statement makes my SQL query take way too long

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query where I get a list of all orders within a date range

This is what the `WHERE` clause of my query looks like

```
WHERE o.Company_Code = LEFT(@Site,2)
  AND o.Division_Code = RIGHT(@Site,3) 
  AND o.Customer_Number = 'ecom2x'
  AND o.Date_Entered BETWEEN @FromDate AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @ToDate)
ORDER BY
    o.date_entered DESC
```

It chooses which company by reading the parameter site which has a value of something like "09001" (which is selected in the report this query builds).

I want to add the functionality to be able to see all orders from all companies. So I added a parameter option "All" to the report with a value of "00000".

This is my new `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE 
    o.Customer_Number = 'ecom2x'
    AND o.Date_Entered BETWEEN @FromDate AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @ToDate)
    AND ((@Site = '00000') OR (o.Company_Code = LEFT(@Site, 2) 
          AND o.Division_Code = RIGHT(@Site, 3))) 
ORDER BY
    o.date_entered DESC
```

The idea is, if the site parameter is 00000, then it should not check the company or division code of the order. If it is not 00000, then it does check it as regular.

Running this query with hard coded values seems to work and gives me the results almost instantly, but when I try to run it as a report, it takes minutes and often crashes.

Comment: Often, conditions with `OR` are hard to optimize.  One approach is to split the query into two queries, and use `union all`.

Comment: It looks like you have a not wanted elipse after `@Site = '00000'` or you forgot to enclose the last 2 *lines* of the WHERE clause in elipses.

Comment: Just to double check my understanding, *should* the clauses `o.Customer_Number = 'ecom2x' AND o.Date_Entered BETWEEN @FromDate AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @ToDate)` be ignored if `@Site` doesn't have a value of `'00000'`? (Currently they would be)

Comment: To make sure that you are running the same query in the report and in your tests: Use Sql Profiler and capture the running query executed by the report app and compare that to the query you are using to test with. You can also use the same tool to get the chosen execution plan and compare that to the execution plan that your query uses in SSMS.

Comment: @Igor. I see what you mean, I think you mean parentheses though. I have implemented TheMouseMaster solution but the problem still persists.

Comment: @Larnu It should always check ecom2x and the date range. Then if Site is 00000 it should give me all orders, if not it should give me orders based on the company and division code of site. Why would it ignore those first two fields currently, it is before the conditional?

Comment: You have an `OR` later. Parenthesis are important. :) Also is this an SP? If so, you *might* want to use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` as the query plans could be quite different for when `@Site'` has a value of `'00000'`.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? And does it speed the query any if you run your functions (`LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `DATEADD`) on your `@` variables before your query rather than inside your query? How many rows are you working with?

Comment: One other comment RE: `Date_Entered BETWEEN @FromDate AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @ToDate)` >> SQL `BETWEEN` is inclusive of both dates. It's the equivalent of `Date_Entered >= @FromDate AND Date_Entered <= DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @ToDate)` I'm not sure if you're adding a day to use a `BETWEEN`, but it may not be necessary. Also, depending on your datatypes and the precision of your time, you may be excluding days you didn't mean to. ie: To SQL `datetime`, `2019-01-01 23:59:59.999` is the same as `2019-01-02 00:00:00.000` because the precision will automatically round up.

Answer (score 2):

this may be order-of-operation regarding ANDs and ORs.

Try this:

```
WHERE 
o.Customer_Number = 'ecom2x'
AND o.Date_Entered BETWEEN @FromDate AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @ToDate)
AND ((@Site = '00000')
    OR 
    (o.Company_Code = LEFT(@Site,2) and o.Division_Code = RIGHT(@Site,3))) 
order by o.date_entered desc
```

Comment: I changed my code to match yours as yours is actually correct but the problem is still there and the query still times out.

Comment: Then I suggest either Gordon Linoff's multi-query+union all suggestion, or seeing if perhaps the table in question could stand to use a new Index